# List ocurrences in column - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, histogram

I have a table column that has integers, for example:

```
2
2
1
2
3
1
3
```

How do I get the values that occur in this column? In this case the results should be:

```
1
2
3
```

I know there's something is Postgre called `width_bucket` but I couldn't make that work me and I'm not even sure if that is supposed to solve my problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Um, not sure I'm understanding your question -- `select distinct ... order by...` would achieve your results...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon your question, it is a simple `select distinct` and then an `order by`

```
SELECT distinct(Column_Name)
FROM Table_name
ORDER BY Column_Name DESC
```

Or

```
SELECT distinct(Column_Name)
FROM Table_name
ORDER BY Column_Name
```

Depending on the Sort order that you want

Comment: This sorts `Column_Name` in descending order, while OP example has an ascending order.

Comment: Good catch, i have added the other option based upon which order the OP wants

Comment: You can omit `ASC`, it's a default option.

Comment: You are correct, it is the default or can be explicitly included, I removed it for the default option

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinct` keyword or `group by` clause with the `order by`:

```
select distinct col from tbl order by col
select col from tbl group by col order by col
```

Comment: @MarcusAdams: Did know about it in MySQL (however [relying on implicit order seems to be  deprecated since 5.6](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html) ), but what about Postgres?